# Generate Multiple Matrix in R

Tags: r

**I have gotten two lists of values in R.**

```
daily_max_car: (List 1)
21 21 22 22 22 22 21 
daily_0.8: (List 2)
16 17 17 17 18 17 17
```

**Trying to write a For Loop in R-Studio to generate multiple matrix by using the one of the values from these two lists (One by One).**

Here is the code I have been using to generate one matrix!

```
 Lambda <- 21 (From List 1)
 Mue <- 4
 Rho <- Lambda/Mue
 N <- 16 (From List 2)
```

All of these four parameters will be used in the "calculatewq" Function.

```
calculatewq <- function(c)
{....Some thing happening }

##Create Matrix
matrix1 <- matrix(0,Lambda,4)
matrix1[,1] <- 1:Lambda
### Create a column of matrix with repeated "N"
rep.row<-function(x,y)
{matrix(rep(x,each=y),nrow=y)}
created_mar_1 <- rep.row(N,Lambda)
car_n<- created_mar_1-matrix1[,1]
created_mar_3 <- rep.row(69*60*24,Lambda)

## Add into Matrix
for (i in 1:Lambda)
{matrix1[i,2] <- calculatewq(i)[2]
matrix1[i,3] <- calculatewq(i)[5]
matrix1[,4] = car_n*created_mar_3}`
```

Once I change one of the parameters it will generate a new matrix. 
Thus, how can I write a for loop to generate multiple matrix while I am putting different value in Lambda and N.

Thank you so much! 
Sampson

Comment: Please read [mcve]! Your code is **not** minimal. What is your desired output? How your code relates on the two lists of values `daily_max_car: 21 21 22 22 22 22 21 daily_0.8: 16 17 17 17 18 17 17` ? Please edit your question: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42872805/edit

Comment: Here, I updated my question.Thank you!